# Apache Ignite Cache ClassNotFoundException

Tags: classnotfoundexception, ignite

I have an apache ignite cluster.

All nodes are splited to two logical groups: platform level nodes (**PLN**) and application level nodes (**ALN**). Each node in cluster has:

- xml configuration file (ALN contain PLN config and application specific cache configs)
- filter class to detect ALN

ALN contain POJO classes to work with Ignite cache, PLN does not contain this classes and **doesn't fit the nodeFilter**.

**BUT** **PLN** on startup (joining to cluster with ALN) attempt to apply ALN cache configuration and catch **ClassNotFoundException** related to application POJO classes.

Could ignite server node ignore cache config if it doesn't fit to nodeFilter ?

Answer (score 0):

All Ignite nodes need to have all cache configurations in the cluster.

`nodeFilter` only constraints set of nodes that hold the data for cache. All nodes in the cluster can query any caches, hence they need this information.

You *could* have two clusters if you wanted, even inside single JVM (per node). This way they won't interact in any way.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite doesn't need to have Key/Value classes in classpath on server side in the most of cases if binary object concept[1] is used in user code that should be executed on server-side.

However, user classes mentioned in Ignite configuration must be in class path on all nodes. If you need SQL indices and use binary objects, then you can create indices dynamically via SQL query on grid startup.

Please, take a look at BinaryObject concept [1]. Hope it helps.

[1] https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#section-basic-concepts

Comment: Thanks for the clarification